# Is there any way to force a Git merge conflict without touching branches?

Tags: git, github, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

Situation:

I have a branch `master` and a branch `feature`. I want to make changes in `feature` and PR them to master, with some of the changes being marked as merge conflicts.

To illustrate, say there's a file test.txt in branch `master` like this.

```
foo
```

`Feature` looks like this

```
bar
zed
```

I want to create a PR from feature master where some changes (e.g. the change from foo to bar) are marked as merge conflicts and must be manually resolved. Meanwhile, some changes, like the addition of zed, are not marked as conflicts. Essentially, I need manual intervention on those kind of conflicts to be marked and resolved before the PR can be closed, but I don't want all of the changes to be reviewed.

Is there any way to do this? Potentially by writing git conflict markers manually into feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this?

Only by creating an actual conflict.

Merges that can have conflicts<sup>1</sup> have three inputs:

1. a *merge base:* the common commit from which the other two commits descend, for `git merge`, or an artificially chosen commit for `git cherry-pick` or `git revert`, for instance;
2. the *current commit* (`HEAD` or `--ours`, or sometimes *local*);
3. the other commit (sometimes called *other* or *remote* or `--theirs`).

A low-level (in-the-file) conflict occurs *when:*

- there is a difference in some file as seen in the output of `git diff --find-renames` from the merge base to the current copy of the file, *and*
- there is a difference in the same file as seen in the output of `git diff --find-renames` from the merge base to the other commit, *and*
- these changes touch the same lines, or otherwise abut (the end of one is the beginning of the other).

In this particular case, when Git tries to combine the two sets of changes, the changes will collide and you'll see a conflict, unless you use `-Xours` or `-Xtheirs` to automatically choose one out of the two conflicting changes.

(High level conflicts also have the same three inputs, but occur when, e.g., one side of the diff *modifies* the file, and the other side *removes* the file.  There's no set-of-lines in which to have a conflict, but there is still a conflict: should Git keep the modified file, or delete the file entirely?)

---

<sup>1</sup>Any true merge—by which I mean the process of merging, or *to merge* as a verb—can have conflicts.  The phrasing here is meant to paper over the fact that `git merge` sometimes does not perform a merge, when it does a *fast-forward* operation.

Comment: Hmm okay. So a merge conflict can never occur where #1 and #3 are the same.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way to have a base merge, push what's essentially a no-op commit (such as adding whitespace) to master to separate #1 and #3 to force the merge conflict.

Comment: do you know if Git conflict markers have any semantic value (e.g. are they parsed by Git at all) or are they just for visually seeing where the conflicts are? @torek

Comment: Merge conflict markers are not semantically significant to Git. In fact, what's in the work-tree is generally *irrelevant* except to operations like `git add`, which copy from the work-tree to the index, or `git diff`, which (can) compare what's in a commit or in the index to what's in a work-tree.